# Effects of eating healthy food for a limited amount of time

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, brain, physiology

if we for example went on a healthy life style for a limited amount of time like 3 months. Then, we reverted back to our less healthier life style that we initially had. Will the reverted for (less healthier) life style neutralizes the effects of the temporary better (healthier) life style. I know that at first 21 years of the individuals life, nutrition plays a foundation role on the person's health. If you could supply me with a statistical pattern that shows the effects for all age group and for different time period of temporary healthy food consumption?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll be very surprised if anyone has collected such statistics.

Comment: *"first 21 years of the individuals life, nutrition plays a foundation role on the person's health"* - are there some studies which back this up?

Answer (score -1):

At least with effects like inflammation, caused by pro-inflammatory eating & living habits, it seems extremely plausible that your body gets harmed further when on such a lifestyle, and gets some "pause" from being harmed as bad during the time which are on a low-inflammatory lifestyle.
Problems with clogging arteries will get worse quicker when on the "bad" lifestyle than on the "good" lifestyle.

When you speak of "neutralizing" you seem to imply the reversibility of certain health deterioration, forward or backward. Many health issues seem only to get worse with progressing age. Worse slower or faster, but rarely better.

It seems that early stages of e.g. diabetes type II can be reversed by nutrition, though. Jack Challem writes about things like that in the book "*Inflammation Syndrome*". Sorry, no link to studies, but the book has many.
Let me just mention that on this topic, you will also find books written by not so scientific people. It needs some sorting.

As for studies, it may not be exactly what you asked for - showing that "bad" vs. "good" eating can cancel each other out.
But apparently, **eating nothing**, *once in a while*, alternated with "eating normally", can decrease some of the bad effects of the "normal eating"

[Enter "Intermittent Fasting"](https://authoritynutrition.com/10-health-benefits-of-intermittent-fasting/)

Comment: Where in your quote is the claim to *exclusively* reduce fat in a certain area? (which is what you seem to imply)
The quote is 100% correct, your text comprehension score is more like 10%. Yes, you can loose belly fat.
Someone halfway knowledgeable in nutrition and health would know that "belly fat" is especially important fat with regards to diseases that involve inflammation. So they are obviously emphasizing the most relvant kind of fat and say "yes, you can loose some of that!", as fat on the buttocks is apparently not nearly as unhealthy.

Comment: You cannot spot-reduce fat.